# Concurrent use of System.Net.Mail.SendAsync?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net

I want to use [System.Net.Mail.SendAync](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x5x13z6h(v=VS.100).aspx) in an ASP.NET MVC2 application.  I see that it throws an **InvalidOperationException** if there is already a **SendAsync** call in progress.  Does this mean only one **SendAsync** is allowed per host, or per thread?  For example, if I simultaneously have 2 web users from 2 different remote hosts, can each use **SendAsync** at the same time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One instance of `SmtpClient` can only run one asynchronous call at a time. You have to create several clients if you want to run several asynchronous calls.

As different threads have their own instance of `SmtpClient`, they don't collide.